# Using a row's number with IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

How do you IMPORTRANGE from another spreadsheet given that you have the row number you want to import? For example, say I want to import row 79 of a given spreadsheet, I want it to look something like this: `IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_url", "Sheet1!A'"&E2&"':Z'"&E2&"'")`, where E2 contains the value 79.

Answer (score 0):

you are supposed to use `INDIRECT` for that like:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1!A"&INDIRECT("E2")&":Z"&INDIRECT("E2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the single quotes are causing your error...the following formula worked in my tests.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1!A"&E2&":Z"&E2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an If statement

```
=IF(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheetname!E2") = 79, IMPORTRANGE("Url","Sheetname!E2"), "no")
```